# C code stack corruption changing variable

Tags: c, multithreading, stack

I'm hoping that someone can help me out. I have not written much in C code in over a decade and just picked this back up 2 days ago so bear with me please as I am rusty. THANK YOU!

**What:**

I'm working on creating a very simple thread pool for an application. This code is written in C on CodeBlocks using GNU GCC for the compiler. It is built as a command line application. No additional files are linked or included.

The code should create X threads (in this case I have it set to 10) each of which sits and waits while watching an array entry (identified by the threads thread index or count) for any incoming data it might need to process. Once a given child has processed the data coming in via the array there is no need to pass the data back to the main thread; rather the child should simply reset that array entry to 0 to indicate that it is ready to process another input. The main thread will receive requests and will dole them out to whatever thread is available. If none are available then it will refuse to handle that input.

For simplicity sake the code below is a complete and working but trimmed and gutted version that DOES exhibit the stack overflow I am trying to track down. This compiles fine and initially runs fine but after a few passes the threadIndex value in the child thread process (workerThread) becomes corrupt and jumps to weird values - generally becoming the number of milliseconds I have put in for the 'Sleep' function.

**What I have checked:**

- The threadIndex variable is not a global or shared variable.
- All arrays are plenty big enough to handle the max number of threads I am creating.
- All loops have the loopvariable reset to 0 before running.
- I have not named multiple variables with the same name.
- I use atomic_load to make sure I don't write to the same global array variable with two different threads at once *please note* I am rusty... I may be misunderstanding how this part works
- I have placed test cases all over to see where the variable goes nuts and I am stumped.

**Best Guess**

All of my research confirms what I recall from years back; I likely am going out of bounds somewhere and causing stack corruption. I have looked at numerous other problems like this on google as well as on stack overflow and while all point me to the same conclusion I have been unable to figure out what specifically is wrong in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
//#include<unistd.h>
#define ESCAPE 27

int maxThreads = 10;
pthread_t tid[21];
int ret[21];
int threadIncoming[21];
int threadRunning[21];

struct arg_struct {
    char* arg1;
    int arg2;
};
//sick of the stupid upper/lowercase nonsense... boom... fixed
void* sleep(int time){Sleep(time);}


void* workerThread(void *arguments)
{
    //get the stuff passed in to us
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;
    char *address = args -> arg1;
    int threadIndex = args -> arg2;
    //hold how many we have processed - we are unlikely to ever hit the max so no need to round robin this number at this point
    unsigned long processedCount = 0;
    //this never triggers so it IS coming in correctly
    if(threadIndex > 20){
        printf("INIT ERROR! ThreadIndex = %d", threadIndex);
        sleep(1000);
    }
    unsigned long x = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    //as long as we should be running
    while(__atomic_load_n (&threadRunning[threadIndex], __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)){
        //if and only if we have something to do...
        if(__atomic_load_n (&threadIncoming[threadIndex], __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)){


            //simulate us doing something
            //for(x=0; x<(0xFFFFFFF);x++);
            sleep(2001); 
            //the value going into sleep is CLEARLY somehow ending up in index because you can change that to any number you want 
            //and next thing you know the next line says "First thread processing done on (the value given to sleep)
            printf("\n First thread processing done on %d\n", threadIndex);




            //all done doing something so clear the incoming so we can reuse it for our next one
            //this error should not EVER be able to get thrown but it is.... something is corrupting our stack and going into memory that it shouldn't
            if(threadIndex > 20){ printf("ERROR! ThreadIndex = %d", threadIndex); }
            else{ __atomic_store_n (&threadIncoming[threadIndex], 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE); }
            //increment the processed count
            ++processedCount;
        }
        else{Sleep(10);}
    }
    //no need to do atomocity I don't think for this as it is only set on the exit and not read till after everything is done
    ret[threadIndex] = processedCount;
    pthread_exit(&ret[threadIndex]);
    return NULL;
}



int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;
    int *ptr[21];
    int doLoop = 1;
    //initialize these all to set the threads to running and the status on incoming to NOT be processing
    for(i=0;i < maxThreads;i++){
            threadIncoming[i] = 0;
            threadRunning[i] = 1;
    }
    //create our threads
    for(i=0;i < maxThreads;i++)
    {
        struct arg_struct args;
        args.arg1 = "here";
        args.arg2 = i;
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &workerThread, (void *)&args);
        if (err != 0){ printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err)); }
    }
    //loop until we hit escape
    while(doLoop){
        //see if we were pressed escape
        if(kbhit()){ if(getch() == ESCAPE){ doLoop = 0; } }
        //just for testing - actual version would load only as needed
        for(i=0;i < maxThreads;i++){
            //make sure we synchronize so we don't end up pointing into a garbage address or half loading when a thread accesses us or whatever was going on
            if(!__atomic_load_n (&threadIncoming[i], __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)){
                __atomic_store_n (&threadIncoming[i], 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
            }
        }
    }
    //exiting...
    printf("\n'Esc' pressed. Now exiting...\n");
    //call to end them all...
    for(i=0;i < maxThreads;i++){ __atomic_store_n (&threadRunning[i], 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE); }
    //join them all back up - if we had an actual worthwhile value here we could use it
    for(i=0;i < maxThreads;i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i], (void**)&(ptr[i]));
        printf("\n return value from thread %d is [%d]\n", i, *ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

Here is the output I get. Note that how long it takes before it starts going crazy does seem to possibly vary but not much.

[Output Screen with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVqbm.png)

Comment: ' a very simple thread pool' - doesn't look all that simple to me.   Usually, 'not simple' means 'won't work correctly', especially when applied to mutithreaded apps.   Most actually-simple threadpools queue tasks to worker threads that loop around a blocking producer-consumer queue.  It's well-known design that works well, needs no wasteful CPU-polling, latency-adding Sleep() loops or any kind of 'management thread'.  Micro-managing thread instances in arrays is complex, wasteful and almost sure to go wrong.  Sure enough... :)

Comment: `else{Sleep(10);}` This seems questionable, why is it there? [Use of Sleep(n) in multi-threaded applications](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm#Sleep).

Comment: ^^ yes, prolly some attempt to avoid/mitigate some other problem, probably polling CPU-use:(   Whatever, it's sure to be a misuse of Sleep().

Comment: The sleep function was a misuse for exactly the reason you stated. I do recall that being a bad idea - as I mentioned it's been 13 years since I've really touched this stuff so I'm sure I made it more complex then need be and made stupid mistakes.. I program in a lot of different languages and have for decades but C I've only been using again for a couple days now. I did look around for examples but didn't find much that would work in Windows with straight up C (likely because I didn't fully know what I was looking for) so I figured I would roll my own. Your pointers helped a lot though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't trust your handling of `args`, there seems to be a race condition. What if you create N threads before the first one of them gets to run? Then the first thread created will probably see the `args` for the N:th thread, rather than for the first, and so on.

I don't believe there's a guarantee that automatic variables used in a loop like that are created in non-overlapping areas; after all they go out of scope with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: When you pass a thread the address of a variable, you need to make sure the variable remains valid and has the correct value for as long as the thread might possibly need it to. That was not done here.

Comment: ^^ what @DavidSchwartz says.  OP design is imp.. very difficult to get right and performant.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying I believe. Last time I did any of this was in 2003 so it has been a bit - not surprised I made a dumb mistake. 

That would mean that in theory all of the threads could be accessing each others `args` variable OR worse it could be destructed when the thread starts up. It would seem my better option would be to change the `args` variable from a single variable into an array so each thread gets passed a pointer to that array index and NOT to the actual shared variable?

Comment: Am I following that correctly? I thought I handled that by making the thread copy the value being pointed at into its own private variable. I didn't think about the fact that the thread could create, loop continues on to the next one and then after that the first thread tries to copy from an array which no longer exists.

How does it manage to do any loops at all initially? It seems to create and run all 20 threads with the correct number a few times before failing. Ionly create the threads once. Again, apologies - I'm a quick study usually but it may take me a bit to get this. 

Thank you!!

Comment: @Jason You got it. Using an array is one way. The other way is to have the code that creates the thread `malloc` an object for the thread and have the thread `free` it when it's done.

Comment: Using an array seems like a good solution, just make sure the array itself has a longer life than the loop, i.e. is declared globally (yuck) or at the start of `main()`. The answer to the "how?" is generally "because undefined behavior".

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I have modified the code to put the `struct arg_struct args` declaration right under main and have changed it to a variables as: `struct arg_struct args[21];`. I have also updated the for loop to read 
`args[i].arg2 = i;
err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &workerThread, (void *)&args[i]);`

Unfortunately I still get the same error. Should I post my new code? Would you guys still be willing to help? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - wouldn't touch such a design with a bargepole:(  It's too complex to debug:((

Comment: Fair enough :) Thank you for the pointers earlier! Much appreciated!

Having not done this in so long I'm beginning to think maybe I should have just stuck my toes in the shallow end instead of diving in head first...